# How to save form values in database using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody help me to save these form values in database.I have already created one form.When I clicked on submit button the below validation message is coming.

```
1 error prohibited this post from being saved:

Gender must be accepted
```

Please check the code and help me to save all values in DB.If any error found please make it correct.

My code is as follows:

views/students/index.html.erb

```
 <h1>Choose the option</h1>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Enter student data",students_new_path %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Display your data",students_show_path %>
    </p>

views/students/new.html.erb

<h1>Enter your data</h1>
<%= form_for @student,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
    <% if @student.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@student.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @student.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
      <%= f.radio_button :gender,'Male',:checked => true %>
      <%= f.label :Male  %>
      <%= f.radio_button :gender,'Female' %>
      <%= f.label :Female %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="city">Select the City</label>
      <%= f.select(:city,options_for_select([['Bhubaneswar','Bhubaneswar'],['Cuttack','Cuttack'],['Behrempur','Behrempur'],['Puri','Puri']],selected: "Puri")) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.check_box :terms_service  %> accept terms and service
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

controller/students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def show

  end
  def new
    @student=Student.new

  end
  def create
  @student=Student.new(users_params)
    if @student.save
      flash[:notice]="You have signed up successfully.."
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:notice]="You have not signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
  private
  def users_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:name,:gender,:city,:terms_service)
  end
end
```

model/student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name ,:presence => true,:length => { :minimum => 6 }
  validates :gender, :acceptance => true
  validates :terms_service, :acceptance => true
end
```

migrate\20150114061737_create_students.rb

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :gender
      t.string :city
      t.string :terms_service

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to run this code successfully.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Validation type used for gender field is wrong ie acceptance validation is used when you want to check if a check-box is checked by user in the form. In your situation you should use

```
validates :gender, :presence => true
```